# Vlc.Dotnet.Forms -> Equalizer, Audio Delay and Hue?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, media-player, vlc, libvlc

would like to ask about WinForms Vlc.DotNet.Forms nuget usage of equalizer.

**Equalizer:**

Now, I can set media control everything else, but I cannot find anyway to implement equalizer. Which in actual VideoLAN player seems quite easy to get running:

[image: VideoLAN Player]

[image: Equalizer]

Now, is this feature implemented somewhere in newest version or do I have to turn to 3rd party tools to get real EQ running. I did check also plugins of VLC and seems the actual EQ is some sort of plugin at VLC which would explain why libvlc doesn't give such option thru Vlc.Dotnet.Forms, but if that is the case VlcMediaPlayerOptions at start-up should somehow be able to load the plugin and activate it at startup I am simply not sure how to do that.

**Hue and Audio Delay:**

Hue(VlcControl1.Video.Adjustment.Hue - supposed to be float value and range 0-360)
Audio Delay(VlcControl1.Audio.Delay - supposed to be long value or int64 and range should be -30000 - 30000 milliseconds with 50ms increase decrease).

Now, for some reason delay and hue reports to be 0 and, if I test them they ain't moving no where no matter what value I set them manually after loading media and playback is started.

So, anyone here would have any information about either of issues?

(yes, I did add both issues here as they basically are in same code.)

Comment: As code running all explained above with few hundred features. I did not include actual code as it's unique to my usage and bad for example. However, if needed to solve this I can write example usage of anything what goes to Vlc.Dotnet.Forms know the script very well.

Comment: Also, while at it, if there's some Vlc.Dotnet specialist here, could tell me if there is "visualization" available somewhere for Vlc.Dotnet as in could get something at video screen while playing WAV,MP3,etc music/audio tracks as this is probably similar loading plugin as above to activate/enable equalizer.